# keyboard keys event comparison generate error when letters are too quickly entered

Tags: jquery, compare, key, onkeyup

I can't resolved the problem due probably to jQuery.
Here is my [test](https://codepen.io/Artenis/pen/WNadqBM?editors=1111).

I enter letters inside input.
I expect a specific word.
For each letter entered I compare its position and that le letter is this expected.
If not ,I display an error.
**My code work only if I enter letters one by one each second.**

If I write normally, in two seconds for example, each time the comparison stop and I get undefined value for a specific letter for different words.

I can assume one or multiple issue form one of them:

- It lacks a real time observation function ?
- Too much code to process in a short time ?
- the jquery library takes too much time to process the information ?

Of course, I can reduce my code, but is it really the problem ?

Or my code do to correspond that I expect .

```
if (keyval.length == 1 && e.key != "p") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 2 && e.key != "o") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 3 && e.key != "r") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 4 && e.key != "t") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 5 && e.key != "a") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 6 && e.key != "l") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 7 && e.key != "s") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("focus", "#key", function () {
    $("body").append('<input type="hidden" id="result" data-token="">');
  });

  function erase() {
    $("#result").remove();
    $("#key").val("");
  }
  

  $(document).on("keyup", "#key", function (e) {
    let keyval = $("#key").val();

    let resuval = $("#result").val();
    let whichkey = e.which;
    console.log(keyval.length + "<br/>" + whichkey);
    let chains = whichkey.toString(16);
    $("#result").val(function () {
      return this.value + chains;
    });

    if (keyval == "portals") {
      console.log("portals");
    } else if (keyval != "portals" && keyval.length == 7) {
      console.log("error");
    }
    
    function errorkey(whichkey) {
    alert(
      "You made a typing error. Please start again!" + whichkey
    );
  }

    if (keyval.length == 1 && e.key != "p") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 2 && e.key != "o") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 3 && e.key != "r") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 4 && e.key != "t") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 5 && e.key != "a") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 6 && e.key != "l") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
    if (keyval.length == 7 && e.key != "s") {
      erase();
      errorkey();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("focusout", "#key", function () {
    erase();
  });
});
```

```css
body{background:#666;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="key">
```

Comment: The issue is due to your use of `keyup` and how its processing order interacts with the DOM when multiple events occur in quick succession, ie. the `value` hasn't yet been updated as you press the next key. There are multiple ways you can solve this, however the best approach would depend on what your exact goal is. There's a lot of ways to improve your logic along with this, as having an individual `if` condition per character is far from ideal.

Comment: You get `undefined` because you redefine `whichkey` in the function arguments and don't pass a parameter - so your func is `function errkey(key2 { alert(key2) };  errkey();` - which you should be able to see would give `undefined`.  Change function to `function errorkey() { alert(... + whichkey) }` to use the outer-scoped variable.

Comment: Added some additional debugging - though the `alert` makes it that much harder to test: https://jsfiddle.net/cwu85yg1/  Typing quickly will get the (eg) 2nd `keyup` event after the (eg) 3rd key is pressed so length = 3 but key still = O

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. Unfortunately, I tried keydown function and the issue is bigger. With this one the position of char entered is different as keyup function. the var of input.val() starts to return a value from the second key entered. (tried settimeout and setInterval)
Also I tried to define a script to include all "if" condition with one but none of my test works.
the goal is to ensure that an word is well entered by verifying that the user has not made a typing error because I convert the letter typed and not displayed in .toString(16)

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m. I have carefully observed your code, I understood that the variable "whichkey" created an error but I did not succeed from your code to solve the problem: to manage to observe two keys enter at the same time (located right next to each other on the keyboard). Ex: "portals": the "p" key is always pressed when I press the "o" key.
The input field writes "p" and "o" in a row but the console interprets it in other ways: "o" pressed before "o" (position) or "po" pressed on the same position. 
For the moment I will add a text for the user to type the letters slowly.

Comment: Add a debounce in the keyup event - so you only get the last one.  You'll need to change how you set #keyvalue so that it takes the current value instead of each key separately, but it would fix your issues.

Comment: @freedomn-m.  I will check this soon, I will come back to you to tell you if I succeeded or not.